# Select box Select all / unselect all or select one option restricted multiple options

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Select box, I want to select all options with a single click also unselect all with a single click so if the user wants to select another option so just select only 1 option not multiple.
i want to select / unselect all option on this first option click`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="all">select all /unselect all</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

`

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: I would say that you need to attach an event listener to this select element and then handle the behaviour in a fuction depending if the value its 'all' or a single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Select* is usually used to get only **ONE** value, perhaps you need a checkbox or something like that... but who knows :)

In order to achieve what you want is that you must add an event listener to the *Select* and try to store the 'real' values in a variable maybe this example helps you out.

// Html

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="all">select all /unselect all</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

// Js

```
var allValues = [];

function getAllValues(){
  return $('#mySelect option').toArray().map(({value}) => value)
}

function selectHandler(event) {
  const { target } = event;
  
  if (target && target.value == 'all') {
    allValues = getAllValues()
  } else {
    allValues = [target.value]
  }
  
  // Do something with this
  console.log(allValues)
}

$('#mySelect').on('change', selectHandler)
```